# Python not able to make web server

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I am trying to make a python web server with the Socket module. I am following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_najJkyK46g.

This is my code:

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 8000

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((host, port))
listen_socket.listen(1)

print("Listening on port "+str(port))

while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print(request)

    http_response = "Hello World."

    client_connection.sendall(bytes(http_response.encode('utf-8')))
    client_connection.close()
```

When I go to chrome and enter 127.0.0.1:8000 it doesn't work. It brings up an error saying "This page isn't working". 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response. ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE. Please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is expecting an HTTP response which is a structured protocol, which `Hello World.` doesn't comply with:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_message

> The response message consists of the following:
>
> A status line which includes the status code and reason message (e.g.,
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK, which indicates that the client's request succeeded).
>   Response header fields (e.g., Content-Type: text/html). An empty line.
>   An optional message body. The status line and other header fields must
>   all end with . The empty line must consist of only 
>   and no other whitespace.[31] This strict requirement for  is
>   relaxed somewhat within message bodies for consistent use of other
>   system linebreaks such as  or  alone.[33]

Updating to the following response should work:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Length: 138
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
  <title>An Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.
</body>
</html>
```

If you're going to be making a server to communicate over HTTP I would def recommend a python web http framework, of which there are many. Two very light weight ones being:

- http://flask.pocoo.org/
- https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

Comment: So I'm confused. Do you want me to add that HTML to the python script? That's not possible, right? Could we just do this with one language?